# How does return actually returns in C?

Tags: c, return, bit-manipulation, bit

DAT_1001b50C is a number and I m bit shifting it.
Now I have a question about the following line:

`return DAT_1001b50C >> 0x10 & 0x7fff;`

will this line return

```
DAT_1001b50C >> 0x10
and
DAT_1001b50C >> 0x7fff
```

or will this return

```
(DAT_1001b50C >> 0x10) >> 0x7fff
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Why don't you do a quick test yourself ? And if can't, why not adding parenthesis to be sure of the operators order ?

Comment: You seem to be confused by what `&` means. It's the bitwise 'and' operator. It doesn't mean 'also'.

Comment: Also, if you were to shift by 0x7FFF, the order would make no difference, since the result would be zero regardless, unless you have some sort of ultra long integer datatype with well over 32K bits…

Answer (score 6):

Neither. `DAT_1001b50C >> 0x10 & 0x7fff` is `(DAT_1001b50C >> 0x10) & 0x7fff`. This shifts the value of `DAT_1001b50C` right 16 bits and performs a bitwise AND with `0x7fff`, which keeps the low 15 bits and clears the remaining bits.

Comment: Excellent catch, I remove my first comment.